# How to split an app into 3 to allow independent deployments ? (Rails 3.2, heroku, postgresql, active admin 1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activeadmin

I am building a daily deal app to learn ruby on Rails. I'm pretty newbie but loving learning to  "build stuff".

The app is actually made up of 3 parts:

1. **the public app/website** where internet visitors come check the deals
2. **my admin interface** (on active admin) where I input the deals (product name, dates of validity, prices..)
3. **in-app analytics** where each deal company can check indicators such as nb of people who saw their deal page, number of clicked, and so on...

Right now, I'd like to improve my app because I only have now ONE github repo and when I deploy (with the usual "git push in local and then git push master for heroku), **it "stops/makes unavailable" EVERYTHING for a couple of seconds/minute.**

My goal is to improve the internet visitor experience and allow me to make more iteration/deploys on back end stuff. Indeed the module s2 and 3 change often.
If I only want to deploy changes on modules 2 and 3 (e.g change some stuff in the admin interface), **I don't want the public website(1.) accessed by internet visitors to be "stopped"/unavailable**.

**How can I do this?**
Should I create one gitub repo/app for each "part" ? I fear to have problems such as if I have a model Deal, this model has to be both on the public app (1.) but also on my module 2. (active amdin needs the model) and maybe even the third. Will I have each time to copy paste all the changes in the three apps? **it would be terrible and not scalable!!**. I know it's not good to do that but i don't know what to do then.

So how can I do this in a proper way?

PS: if you know of any "step by step" page or website explaining how to do it in detail, it would be of course great as I think i'll need precise guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have 3 applications, it is only 1 application but with multiple types of users. You can't really avoid deploying your whole codebase every time you update I'm afraid.

The essence of your question is how to avoid user downtime during deployments. This is an important topic for anybody with a hosted application.

The usual culprits causing slow deployments are DB migrations and asset compilation.

A good place to start might be this video - http://railscasts.com/episodes/373-zero-downtime-deployment
It covers non-Heroku deployments, but might start you off in the right direction.

Finally, there is a feature in development from Heroku that you could try called `preboot`. It basically spins up your new dynos before cutting traffic over to them during a deployment. Have a look here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-preboot